# FCM Admin - where are the registration tokens for web app users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following the [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) on the documentations, but I'm confused about registration tokens. I'm testing the push notifications on my local express server. How exactly do I retrieve the current registration token, and how do I generate registration tokens for multiple web app users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the docs it says:

> ```
> // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
> var registrationToken = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN';`
> ```

To get the user's token:

```
 messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
if (currentToken) {
  sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
  updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
} else {
  // Show permission request.
  console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
  // Show permission UI.
  updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
  setTokenSentToServer(false);
}
}).catch(function(err) {
console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });
}
```

more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token)

Then add the token to the database and retrieve it in the Admin SDK

more info here: [Retrieve data in Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: Are these methods (`sendTokenToServer`, `showToken`, etc.) pre-defined? I tried to use this code snippet before, but I got undefined errors because of these functions.

Comment: I see. Just to be clear, by database you mean the Firebase realtime database and not my application's database?

Comment: Yes send it to the firebase realtime database then retrieving it from there

Comment: Yes, thank you. One last thing though, how do I send the token to the database from the client side?

Comment: just save it noormally to the database after you get https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write